# How to optimise CSS3 transitions on DIV resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a large image within a div which I apply a resize transition to. Perhaps it is simply the speed of my computer, however, I am finding that there is a slight delay when actioned, and also the resize itself is not smooth. I have attached a fiddle with a simplified version of the code, and below. Thank you.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myID");
  element.classList.toggle("div_clicked");
}
```

```css
.div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: height 0.65s ease-in-out;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}

.div_clicked {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transition: height 0.65s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="myID" class="div">
  <img onClick="myFunction();" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/obd0yfun/

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me in both the JSFiddle and the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

It's more efficient to use [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) in your case.

"Transitioning certain properties causes the browser to recalculating styles every frame. This is fairly expensive, and can lead to unnecessary re-paints.
`Transform` offload the rendering to the GPU. In simple terms, this turns the element into an image during the transition, avoiding any style recalculations which greatly increases performance." [read more](https://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions)

```css
.div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transform-origin: top left; // default value is "center"
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform:    scale(1);
  -ms-transform:     scale(1);
  -o-transform:      scale(1);
  transform:         scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.65s ease-in-out;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}

.div_clicked {
  transform-origin: top left; // default value is "center"
  -webkit-transform: scale(.25);
  -moz-transform:    scale(.25);
  -ms-transform:     scale(.25);
  -o-transform:      scale(.25);
  transform:         scale(.25);
  transition: transform 0.65s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="myID" class="div">
  <img onClick="myFunction();" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
</div>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var element = document.getElementById("myID");
    element.classList.toggle("div_clicked");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: If you only wanted to increase the height, how would you avoid the contents being skewed?

Comment: This doesn't really do the same thing as OPs code. In this example, after the transition the div is still taking up the same 200px of vertical space in the layout as it was before the transition.

Comment: @Turnip indeed, the layout around the div does not respond in the same way as if the height/width were simply transitioned. I see overlaps.